# Access-Control-Allow-Origin and Servlet as proxy

Tags: java, javascript, servlets, proxy, access-control

I have a servlet that acts as a proxy.
it takes external resources and serves a client (browser) that shows the inside of an iframe.

how can I overcome the problem of Access-Control-Allow-Origin?

In fact, it happens that some external resource open other connections to the original server, but these are denied due to this problem.

The resources are loaded from another server that I cannot control, but I can make changes on the resource once it has been stored in my servlet.

I tried inserting:

```
<script> document.domain=" +ORIGINAL_DOMAIN+ "</ script>
```

but I get a

```
Uncaught Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this on a local file over the `file://` URI scheme, it cannot have cookies set. Put it on a local server so you can use `http://localhost`.
You can also launch chrome with the `--allow-file-access-from-file` command switch, that get rid of this protection security

Comment: i'm using this on an local istance of Tomcat7, and the "external server" resources are real web pages.